# Why is this Linq query tied to a Blazor parameter returning nothing back?

Tags: c#, csv, linq, razor, blazor

I have a Linq query that is attempting to filter data down based on a selected meal type which is located inside a CSV file. The CSV file is being processed by CsvHelper and is represented by a relevant model file.

As one can see below, when I select breakfast (or lunch, dinner or snacks), it returns no data.

Linq query:

```
public partial class EternityDataView : IGenerateNutritionalValues {
    private NutritionDataView dataView = new();
    public decimal? GetCalorieValues()
    {
        var calories = from c in FileUpload.records
            where c.Meal == dataView.SelectedMeal
            select c.Calories;

        return calories.Sum();
    }
```

NutritionDataView meal select razor content:

```
<div class="meal-select">
    <label for="meal-select">Select meal type:</label>
    <select name="meal-select" id="meal-select" @bind="SelectedMeal">
        <option value="all-meals">All meals</option>
        <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
        <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
        <option value="lunch">Lunch</option>
        <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
    </select>
</div>
.......
// Switch for date range
    case "eternity":
        if (SelectedMeal == "all-meals")
        {
            <EternityDataViewAllMeals/>
        }
        else
        {
            <EternityDataView/>
        }
        break;
```

A picture of the EternityDataView component running with breakfast selected as the SelectedMeal:
[image: A picture of a Blazor app]

A picture of the EternityDataViewAllMeals component running with all meals selected as the SelectedMeal:

[image: A picture of a Blazor app #2]

Sample of the CSV:

```
Date,Meal,Calories,Fat (g),Saturated Fat,Polyunsaturated Fat,Monounsaturated Fat,Trans Fat,Cholesterol,Sodium (mg),Potassium,Carbohydrates (g),Fiber,Sugar,Protein (g),Vitamin A,Vitamin C,Calcium,Iron,Note
2023-03-02,Breakfast,105.0,0.4,0.1,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.2,422.4,27.0,3.1,14.4,1.3,5.0,17.1,0.6,1.7,
2023-03-02,Lunch,710.0,30.1,3.2,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.8,214.0,91.8,9.8,44.4,18.1,0.0,15.3,1.2,1.3,
2023-03-02,Dinner,699.8,29.4,7.8,2.4,6.2,0.2,19.8,268.3,180.4,87.2,3.4,28.6,22.6,12.7,84.1,15.8,2.0,
2023-03-02,Snacks,166.0,0.4,0.0,0.1,0.1,0.0,0.0,6.9,615.7,39.6,1.0,28.7,2.4,0.0,193.7,19.4,2.5,
```

I'm a bit confused. As you can see in the image, you can see that the value property is being shown below the drop down, which I used as a bit of a debugging tool. In the Linq query, I have set breakpoints to find that SelectedMeal is null. So I am not quite sure what is happening there. It's worth noting that for all meals, the Linq query inside EternityDataViewAllMeals is just selecting everything and not wondering about the date. I haven't got the slightest idea why SelectedMeal is null.

Maybe I need to groupby?

Comment: You seem to bind to a property `SelectedMeal` which is not the same as `dataView.SelectedMeal`. Try binding to `dataView.SelectedMeal` or use the `SelectedMeal` property.

Comment: Your filters don't match the data, you have `breakfast` as the value in your option but the data has `Breakfast`. You need to either match the case or do a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: @HasaniH To test for that, I edited one CSV record so that it said 'breakfast' and not 'Breakfast'. Nothing showed still.

Comment: @islandmonkey if `SelectedMeal` is still null then you still have a binding problem as @Musroomator mentioned. Once you get past that you'll see the discrepancy with your filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by changing the way I do things and managing changes of selected meal type and selected time period all on NutritionDataView.razor.cs, rather than have separate components for each selected time period.